# Vugen (Loadrunner) not able to record wms and wfs calls

Tags: http, https, loadrunner, wms, vugen

I have an internal website which is completely based on Geo Map and uses HTTP/HTTPS protocol also wfs and wms service calls.

While recording with LR I am able to launch and record all the contents, 
**but after that for next transaction when I click on any of the option to see the map It is not recording in LR.**

For next transaction type of calls are jquery which gets the server response in form of images (geo locations).

I tried recording with HTTP single and HTTP with Web-services multiple protocols also
My LR version is 12.01 and recording it with Chrome browser

Help me out please !

Answer (score 0):

Both WFS and WMS, from the open geospacial consortium, should be using HTTP as a carrier.   Can you provide insight on why such calls to these servers are being ignored

1. Do you have the servers in any sort of filter as a third party element which should not be tested as you do not have ownership or control of the target?
2. Are you electing to connect to these services over a protocol other than HTTP?
3. You note, "Not recording," what is the specific objective evidence that a recording is not occuring?  Lack of evidence in the recording logs?  Lack of an increase in the events counter?   Lack of ??   Please clarify
4. Have you tried the HTTP Proxy method of recording versus the default sockets model?

Comment: 1. We are using internal and external(third party) Geo services, I have access to both.
2. No I am using just HTTP protocol to record these services.
3. It is all checkbox which I am selecting to see the geo location response on Country Map, and those responses are coming in form of images from backend...
I see in Hploadrunner/bin/data/CodeGenerationLog file also noting captured for these checkbox selection response
4. Yes I tried, Application doesn't even launch on proxy and also it records (Launch which I was able to) only on socket level.

Comment: The proxy is based upon Fiddler.  If you can record with Fiddler, then you can record with the LoadRunner proxy.   You can also import a Fiddler trace into the latest versions of Loadunner.   If Fiddler does not capture it, then it is not riding over HTTP.

Comment: Keep in mind, a checkbox on a screen may be implemented as completely in browser as JavaScript and not have any corresponding request.

Comment: James Pully , Your both points are correct with Fiddler also it doesn't capture, Also It is implemented as completely in browser as jquery.
Is there any way to capture it now ?

Comment: "Completely in browser" generates no network traffic to capture, so you would not expect any HTTP layer items.  If you wish to record this "completely in browser" model, then you have TruClient, GUI Virtual User, Citrix Virtual User or Remote Desktop Virtual User